# Logging in spring 3.0 under glassfish?

Tags: spring, netbeans, glassfish, log4j

I'm trying to debug why certain handlers in one of my controllers is not invoked by Spring's AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.  I don't get any errors in Netbeans, just a 404 in the browser.  I tried placing a breakpoint in one of my working controllers/handlers then walking up the chain to place a breakpoint in the dispatcher.

Netbeans shows me some funny method bodies:

```
protected ModelAndView invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
{
  //compiled code
  throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
```

which I suspect is caused by the AOP magiq.  Undeterred, I tried to configure log4j to trace the calls and display any messages logged at debug level from the org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation package, but just by creating a log4j.properties file and putting in the classpath I get nothing more than the default "INFO:" level messages.  Adding the context-param and listener in web.xml fails because the container can't find the log4j classes, even though they are there and even though I can add them again to the project.

So, the question is -- what do I need to do to get method traces (this could be done through AOP) and enhanced debugging (this definitely needs log4j) under Spring 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken Spring 3.X uses SLF4J for logging. Usually you would need to add SLF4J binding for your logging framework of choice - for example, for log4, slf4j-log4j12 jar should be present in classpath as well as log4j.jar and they better be proper versions - I found SLF4J to be picky about that. See more details [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/). Also don't forget log4j.xml config.

Comment: I saw that page but what I need is a recipe - type "foo" in file "bar" and deploy.  Note that I tried things as described here http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-17929.html - but I get class not found exceptions.

Comment: Well, I can't give you precise because I don't know your packaging/deployment process but basically you would need to make sure there are NO jcl-over-slf4j*.jar in your app classpath (WEB-INF/lib), add slf4j-log4j12*.jar and log4j*.jar into classpath (WEB-INF/lib) and make log4j.xml available (usually in WEB-INF/classes)

Comment: Spring uses Commons Logging by default. The page you linked to explains how to use SLF4J instead (using the JCL to SLF4J bridge). But the OP doesn't have to switch to SFL4J to solve his issue.